# Adobe CQ6 - Runaway ContentFinder

Tags: aem, slf4j, jcr

Starting on 1/13, our Adobe CQ6.0 SP1 error logs started filling up with:

> GET /bin/wcm/contentfinder/product/view.json/etc/commerce/products HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.strategy.ContentMirrorStoreStrategy Traversed 1041307000 nodes using index jcr:lastModified with filter Filter(query=select [jcr:path], [jcr:score], * from [nt:base] as a where isdescendantnode(a, '/etc/commerce/products') order by [jcr:lastModified] desc /* xpath: /jcr:root/etc/commerce/products//* order by @jcr:lastModified descending */, path=/etc/commerce/products//*)

The error logs are huge and AEM 6.0 ran out of disk space:

```
error.log.2015-01-13: 30295763555 bytes
error.log.2015-01-14: 52886323200 bytes
```

We are able to reproduce the problem by issuing the following HTTP request against AEM Author:

```
GET /bin/wcm/contentfinder/product/view.json/etc/commerce/products
```

This issue suddenly on 1/13/2015, 9:47 a.m., with a co-worker loading a site in AEM 6.0, and ContentFinder never loaded, so she removed `cf#`, and then was able to proceed with the authoring of the content itself.

We are interested in knowing if others have had similar issues with ContentFinder in AEM6.0.

Comment: Does you error.log contain any entry e.g. warnings that indicates missing indexes?

Comment: No, Thomas.  No missing index messages in the error logs.

Comment: Can you please check your oak:index node.
Does it contain an ordered cqLastModified oak:QueryIndexDefinition?
Which oak version are you currently using? Have you tried to upgrade to 1.0.7 using hotfix cq-6.0.0-hotfix-5176?

Comment: Thanks so much!  The software has a bug in the QueryBuilder for 1.0.5.  I have been asked to upgrade to 1.0.9.  Also, part of the upgrade was to install two sample index creation packages:  http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem6-available-hotfixes.html  Things look stable now - the content finder loads up and does not spin.

Comment: And, yes, there is an ordered "cqLastModified" QueryindexDefinition.  Sorry, but we are new to the software.  What is the significance of the cqLastModified QueryIndexDefinition?  Thanks, again.

Comment: It defines that the cq:LastModified property is indexed. If you use an non-indexed property in your query, oak will traverse the repository structure.
If you are new to AEM I would recommend you to read and understand the documentation for it's building blocks e.g. the oak documentation  http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html

Answer (score 2):

AEM 6.0 has a bug in the Querybuilder related to Oak 1.0.5.  We need Oak to be upgraded to v1.0.9.  The following URI has more information:

http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/aem6-available-hotfixes.html

SP1 needs to be installed first and then the hot fixes need to be installed in the given order over SP1.  The two sample index packages (`damLucene.zip` and `productsIndex.zip`) need to be installed as well.  These add the following indices:

- `/oak:index/damLucene`
- `/etc/commerce/products/ntbaseProductsLucene`